# Removing a node of a linked list in a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

After spending more than 10 hrs, the following code is developed:

```
struct stockRecord* temp = NULL;
struct stockRecord* head = NULL;
struct stockRecord* prevptr = NULL;
struct stockRecord* recurfun(struct stockRecord* list) {

   temp = list;
   if (head == NULL) head = temp;
   if (temp == NULL) {
      return head;
   } else {
      /*first node*/
      if (prevptr == NULL) {

         if (strstr(temp->name, "ABC-") != NULL) {

            temp = temp->next;

            head = temp;
        prevptr = head;

         }  
      }
      /*last node*/
      if (temp->next == NULL) {
         if (strstr(temp->name, "ABC-") != NULL) {
            prevptr->next = NULL;

         }
         return head;
      }
      /*middle node*/

         if (strstr(temp->name, "ABC-") != NULL) {
               prevptr->next = temp->next;

         } else {
               if (prevptr != NULL) {
                 prevptr = temp;
               } else {
                 prevptr = head;
               }
         }

      return recurfun(temp->next);      

   }
```

The problem is, when first node and the second node also contains "ABC-", the function only remove the first node, the second node still can't be removed.

What's the problems of my code?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you start out with `1->2->3`

After you remove the first node, you set `prevptr`, `head`, and `temp` to all point to `2`.

Then at the end of the function you recursively call it on `temp->next` which points to `3`.

The result is that you are skipping the second node when you remove the first.